# What is the difference between spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-rest and ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG?

Tags: spring-kafka

In application.properties, i have this:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=latest
```

and in KafkaConsumerConfiguration.java, i have this:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs(){
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");

    return props;
}
```

I guess they are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same thing.

When using Boot's auto configuration for the consumer factory, that property is mapped to `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG`.

See [Boot's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-kafka-extra-props).

> The properties supported by auto configuration are shown in Appendix A, Common application properties. Note that, for the most part, these properties (hyphenated or camelCase) map directly to the Apache Kafka dotted properties. Refer to the Apache Kafka documentation for details.
>
> The first few of these properties apply to all components (producers, consumers, admins, and streams) but can be specified at the component level if you wish to use different values. Apache Kafka designates properties with an importance of HIGH, MEDIUM, or LOW. Spring Boot auto-configuration supports all HIGH importance properties, some selected MEDIUM and LOW properties, and any properties that do not have a default value.
>
> Only a subset of the properties supported by Kafka are available directly through the KafkaProperties class. If you wish to configure the producer or consumer with additional properties that are not directly supported, use the following properties: ...

Since you are not using auto configuration (you are defining your own configs), the Boot property is ignored.